# Groebner bases for power series rings (reference request)

Tags: power-series, ac.commutative-algebra, groebner-bases, reference-request

Hello,

Could you help me with a reference to elementary properties of Groebner bases in rings of formal power series over a field? I am especially interested in generic initial ideals.

Thank you in advance,
Serge

Comment: Have you looked at Greuel, Pfister, A Singular Introduction to Commutative Algebra? I think it contains a few sections on power series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Michael's comment, the Greuel, Pfister book Section 6.4 is about standard bases in formal power series rings.  Quoting,

> The main result is that they can be computed, if the ideal is
>   generated by polynomials. This is the basis for computations in local analytic
>   geometry. The theory of standard bases in power series rings goes back to
>   Hironaka (cf. [123]) and Grauert (cf. [98]).

The references are:

- Hironaka, H.: Resolution of Singularities of an Algebraic Variety over a Field
  of Characteristic Zero. Ann. of Math. 79, 109–326 (1964).
- Grauert, H.: Über die Deformation isolierter Singularitäten analytischer Mengen. Invent. Math. 15, 171–198 (1972).

Answer (score 1):

The only place where I think I read about Groebner bases for power series was "Coherent Analytic Sheaves" by Grauert and Remmert, but I don't think they got this far.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a nice treatment of standard bases in the ring of convergent power series in the book of De Jong and Pfister "Local analytic geometry: Basic theory and applications" (it's chapter 7).